# Problema Paginación PHP

Tags: php, mysql, paginacion

Estoy trabajando con PHP, tengo una lista con paginación que funciona bien pero al ir cargando muchos registros me di cuenta de un detalle. La paginación solo debería mostrar 5 paginas, pero mi paginación me muestra todas las paginas, creando una gran fila con números de paginas. Comparto mi codigo, esperando que alguien pueda orientarme a resolver este problema.

ASI DEBERIA SER

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

ASI FUNCIONA ACTUALMENTE
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
  $sql_register = $db->query("SELECT COUNT(*) as total_registro FROM pasantia");
  $result_register = mysqli_fetch_array($sql_register);
  $total_registro = $result_register['total_registro'];
         
  $solicitudesPorPagina = 10;
  $pagina = 1;

  if (isset($_GET["pagina"])) 
  {
    $pagina = $_GET["pagina"];
  }
  $limit = $solicitudesPorPagina;
  $offset = ($pagina - 1) * $solicitudesPorPagina;
  $paginas = ceil($total_registro / $solicitudesPorPagina);
```

/////////////////////////////PAGINACION//////////////////////////

```
  <nav aria-label="Page navigation example">
   <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
        <p>Mostrando <?php echo $solicitudesPorPagina ?> de <?php echo $total_registro ?> 
   solicitudes disponibles</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
        <p>Página <?php echo $pagina ?> de <?php echo $paginas ?> </p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <ul class="pagination justify-content-right">
    <?php if ($pagina > 1) { ?>
        <li>
            <a href="./pasantia.php?pagina=<?php echo $pagina - 1 ?>">
                <span aria-hidden="true">&laquo;</span>
            </a>
        </li>
    <?php } ?>
    <?php for ($x = 1; $x <= $paginas; $x++) { ?>
        <li class="<?php if ($x == $pagina) echo "active" ?>">
            <a href="./pasantia.php?pagina=<?php echo $x ?>">
                <?php echo $x ?></a>
        </li>
    <?php } ?>
    <?php if ($pagina < $paginas) { ?>
        <li>
            <a href="./pasantia.php?pagina=<?php echo $pagina + 1 ?>">
                <span aria-hidden="true">&raquo;</span>
            </a>
        </li>
    <?php } ?>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hay más formas de resolverlo, pero ésta podría ser una de ellas. Me centro en el bucle `for ($x = 1; $x <= $paginas; $x++)` que podrías cambiar por el siguiente bloque de código.

Al principio defino una variable `$margen_pags = 2` porque entiendo que querrías, por ejemplo si estás en la 6, ver 4-5-6-7-8, pero puedes cambiarlo por cualquier valor si por ejemplo mañana quieres 3 antes y tres después.

Y un tema importante es que pongo el código entendiendo que la primera página empieza a contar en 1. Si empezara en 0 habría que hacer algún retoque.

También quizá convendría valorar qué pasa si no hay resultados (`$total_registro == 0`), porque en ese caso no habría que poner ningún paginador y este código puede provocar algún error, así que no sé si lo evalúas antes de cualquier otra cosa (no veo dónde), pero es importante.

Espero que te valga

```
<?php 
    $margen_pags = 2;
    for ($x = ($pagina - $margen_pags); $x <= ($pagina + $margen_pags); $x++) { 
        if ($x >= 1 && $x <= $paginas) {        
?>
            <li class="<?php if ($x == $pagina) echo "active" ?>">
                <a href="./pasantia.php?pagina=<?php echo $x ?>">
                    <?php echo $x ?></a>
            </li>
<?php 
        }
    } 
?>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, me sirvió y solucioné el problema.

Comment: Si te sirvió y el resto está bien, podrías marcar la respuesta como "Aceptada"... https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/428/278458

Comment: Listo, respuesta aceptada.